What is difference between Sanskrit used in Mahabharata, The Sanskrit used in Ramayana, The Sanskrit Used in Bhagvad Geeta and Panini Sanskrit?
I have been exploring the variations in Sanskrit used across different historical texts and would appreciate some detailed insights. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the linguistic differences between the Sanskrit used in the Mahabharata, Ramayana, Bhagavad Gita, and the classical Sanskrit of Panini's Ashtadhyayi.
From my research on Wikipedia and Quora, I've gathered the following points:
Epic Sanskrit (Mahabharata and Ramayana):** The Sanskrit in these epics is often considered earlier than Panini's Classical Sanskrit but later than Vedic Sanskrit. The Ramayana, for instance, does not always adhere to Panini's grammatical rules, and similar deviations can be found in the Mahabharata.
Bhagavad Gita: This text is classified as Epic-Puranic Sanskrit, suggesting it was composed after Panini but before the prevalence of long compounds typical of Classical Sanskrit.
Panini's Mention of Mahabharata: Panini mentions the Mahabharata in his Ashtadhyayi, indicating that the epic existed before or during his time.
Given these points, I have a few specific questions:
Linguistic Differences: What are the notable linguistic differences between the Sanskrit used in the earlier parts of the Mahabharata and the Bhagavad Gita?
Chronological Context: How does the chronology of these texts reflect the evolution of Sanskrit from Vedic to Classical periods?
Deviations from Panini: Could you provide examples where the Ramayana and Mahabharata deviate from Panini's grammatical constructs, and what might these deviations signify about the language evolution?
Epic-Puranic Sanskrit: What are the defining characteristics of Epic-Puranic Sanskrit, and how does it bridge the gap between Panini's Sanskrit and the Sanskrit found in the epics?
Mahabharata vs. Ramayana: What are the linguistic differences between the Sanskrit used in the Mahabharata and that of the Ramayana? How do these differences reflect the linguistic and stylistic evolution within the Epic Sanskrit period?
I am looking for a comprehensive analysis that delves into both the grammatical and historical aspects of these differences. Any scholarly references or examples from the texts would be greatly appreciated.
